# Simple way to increase a number (Variable) every time page loads with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I need to set a variable equal to number of page load, or page count. something like:

```
var x = numberofpageload;
```

and number of page load should be saved in local storage in case the browser closes or refreshes.

Thanks

Comment: Client side cookies. If you need further guidance with this just ask. :)

Comment: What code have you tried?  Do you want this to only work on systems that support local storage or do you want it to work in older browsers too?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question "page load should be saved in local storage" . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function refresher()
{
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  if (localStorage.refresh)
    {
    localStorage.refresh=Number(localStorage.refresh)+1;
    }
  else
    {
    localStorage.refresh=1;
    }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="" + localStorage.refresh + " time(s).";
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>
```

then on body load I call the function and this variable changes.